# Qml Nested List Model Append Data

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qqmlcomponent

I have my list mode

```
  ListModel {
            id: nestedModel
          }
```

and I can append the list model using the code

```
nestedModel.append({
     locationName: qsTr("Location5"),
    collapsed: true,
       folders: [{
                  folderName: qsTr("Cam11")
                  }, {
                  folderName: qsTr("Cam22")
                  }, {
                  folderName: qsTr("Cam33")
                  }, {
                 folderName: qsTr("Cam44")
                 }]
             })
```

Which works fine.

But I need to append the inner list only using the same append model, like I have already `Cam11,Cam22,Cam33,Cam44` in my list model, and I have to append `Cam55,Cam66` dynamically.

How it’s possible?

Any help will be appreciated…

Thanks
Haris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the answer [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/632795/QML-TreeModel-and-TreeView)

We can append new data to child list using,

```
nestedModel.get(index).folders.append({"folderName": "Cam55"})
nestedModel.get(index).folders.append({"folderName": "Cam66"})
```